# Vuetify Icons does not work on Firefox 61.0.1

Tags: firefox, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have issue that my v-icon is not displaying on Mozilla Firefox 61.0.1 (latest version). On previous versions of Mozilla this was working.

```
<v-icon>mood</v-icon>
```

Now it is displaying only "mood"

[image]

Has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: yes I have the same issue

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

there's an error in the auto generated index.html (if you're using vue cli 3 and Vuetify)

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100:300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

should be

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```